# local variable 'results' referenced before assignment

Tags: solr, search-engine, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I want to retrieve all indexes under elasticsearch index folder. I got this error.

```
UnboundLocalError at /tjobfucksearch/

local variable 'results' referenced before assignment
```

my views.py

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
def fucksearch(request):

    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        results = SearchQuerySet().all()

    return render_to_response("tjob/fucksearch.html", {
        "results": results,
        "query": query
    })
```

my urls.py

```
url(r'^tjobfucksearch/$', 'tjob.views.fucksearch'),
```

Plus: haystack 2.0.0, django 1.4
Any advice would be appreciated. Plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where no `q` parameter is provided. Then `query` is set to `''`, the `if query` condition fails, so results is not set (not even set to `None`; Python doesn't know about the name `results` at this point). So it fails when you try to get the value from `results` to pass it into the context dict for `render_to_response`. Perhaps add:

```
results = None
```

before:

```
if query:
    ....
```

This way, `results` will always be defined by the time you need to pass it to render. (You still have to handle the none-results case in your template!)

Comment: thanks, @joeln . how to handle it in template?As follow? 
            {% if query %}
             
            {% for result in page.object_list %}
                {{ result.object.title }}
            {% empty %}            
                 <p>No results</p>
            {% endfor %}

Comment: I don't have enough information to say, but probably something like: `{% for result in results %}` rather than `{% for result in page.object_list %}` as above you don't define a context variable `page`.